# Select rows from dataframe based on isclose() condition

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe `orig_df` with "Alpha" and "Method" column names.

`num` is a floating point number with some floating point error. For example, it is 1.1400000000000001.

Meanwhile, "Alpha" values are truncated to 1.14.

As a result, I want to return all the rows such that `orig_df["Alpha"]` and `num` are close (and that `method` matches some string `method_type`, but that's less relevant).

So far I have:

```
temp_df = orig_df[
                (math.isclose(orig_df["Alpha"], num))
                & (orig_df["Method"] == method_type)
            ]
```

But then i receive the error

```
TypeError: cannot convert the series to <class 'float'>
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`math.isclose` is not a function that can cooperate with `pandas` and `numpy` arrays.

You need `numpy.isclose`:

```
temp_df = orig_df[
                (np.isclose(orig_df["Alpha"], num))
                & (orig_df["Method"] == method_type)
            ]
```

`np` is `numpy` in this case.